# How to use patterns to return non-overlapping sequences of consecutive elements from an array

Tags: pattern-matching

Let me first describe the data structure I'm looking at before describing my question.  I have an array of nx3 elements with a data-generating process such that each row has the format:

{previous row's Last element, new random integer, sum of previous row's last element and new random integer} (note: the first row's first element is constrained to be zero)

Here's a function to create such an array of some length n using a range of integers (e.g. {-10,10}):

```
randomArray[range_List, length_Integer]:=
Module[{
vals=RandomInteger[range, {length}],
totals
},
totals = FoldList[Plus, 0, vals];
Thread[{totals, Append[vals, 0], 
Append[Rest@totals, Last@totals]}]
];
```

My question is how can I use `PatternSequence[]` to list out all cases of runs of consecutive elements.  More specifically, I wish to find the shortest sequence of elements where the first row's last element is positive and thus has the pattern `{_,_,_?Positive}`.  This will then be followed by zero or more elements with the same pattern and finally concluded with a row with the pattern `{_,_,_?PossibleZeroQ}`.  So my code for what I thought would work is as follows:

```
Shortest[PatternSequence[{_, _, _?Positive}, ___, {_, _, 
_?PossibleZeroQ}]]
```

...which could be applied to `Cases[]` at level 1 or `ReplaceAll[]` etc., but it does not return what I'm looking for.

For example, given the explicit test data structure given by:

```
data={{0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0}, {0, -6, -6}, {-6, 8, 2}, {2, 9, 11}, 
{11, 6, 17}, {17, -10, 7}, {7, 10, 17}, {17, 2, 19}, {19, -10, 9}, 
{9, 0, 9}};
```

...then I would expect to use...

```
Cases[data, 
Shortest[PatternSequence[{_, _, _?Positive}, ___, {_, _, 
_?PossibleZeroQ}]], {1}, 1]
```

...to return the first such pattern found as in

```
{{0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0}}
```

...but I only get `{}` returned.

My goal is to return a list of all such patterns, but as I only used `Cases[]` here to attempt to get the first pattern, it still did not work.

Am I using `PatternSequence[]` or something else incorrectly here or missing a pattern object such as `Repeated` or something like that?  I appreciate any input on the matter.

I also realize that I can use `Split[]` or a close-cousin to perform this operation, but I would like to attempt to get the results if possible using pattern objects and pattern tests.  Thank you!

Comment: @march, thank you for the catch.  I had done some other processing on my example data which caused the error.  Using the provided `randomArray[]` function works to produce the correct structure however.  Thanks for catching my error!  I've made the edits.

Comment: I'm a little confused about this: "My question is how can I use `PatternSequence[]` to list out all cases of runs of consecutive elements. More specifically, I wish to find the shortest sequence of elements where the first row's last element is positive and thus has the pattern `{_,_,_?Positive}`". Is the first question what you actually want to do and the second one step on the way that helps you understand how to use `PatternSequence`?

Comment: A point of clarification: you want to "list out all cases of runs of consecutive elements". To me, that reads as "find sequences `n, n+1, n+2, ...`, which can only ever happen *within* one of your lists, and it can only be `{0, 1, 2}`. Do you mean runs of the *same* element (which is suggested by the code you're working on)? In that case, you can never get runs going over more than two lists, due to the summation, so why not remove the `___` between the lists in your pattern?

Comment: Hi @march, thanks for your help.  To clarify, when I say "list out all cases", I'm saying the elements of the list will each be a "run", where a "run" is defined as a list whose elements are all of the form `{_, _, _?Positive}` except the last element, which should be in the form `{_, _, _?PossibleZeroQ}`.  And further, the constraint I want to impose is that the sequence of elements of each "run" is the shortest possible consecutive sequence and are thus in the same order as the original data list. I hope that clarifies things somewhat.

Comment: In case you're interested, I think it's a good idea to post an answer using `SequenceCases`, if you were ever able to get that to work. I think it would be a useful addition to this Q&A. (I will upvote if you do: send me a comment if you do it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Based on OP's comments, here's how I would go about solving this problem pre-V10.1 (the OP is correct that `SequenceCases` is the best option here, but it was introduced in V10.1). We want to find all runs, where a "run" is defined as a sequence of elements in which the last element in the list is always positive, and the run ends when the last element in the list is 0. For the purposes of making sure things work out, I'm going to use the modified list

```
data = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0}
         , {0, -6, -6}
         , {-6, 8, 2}, {2, 9, 11}, {11, 6, 17}, {17, -18, -1}
         , {-1, 11, 10}, {10, -4, 6}, {6, -6, 0}
         , {-1, 1, 0}
         , {9, -9, 0}};
```

I've broken it up in this way to illustrate that there are some sequences that it *shouldn't* match and some that it should. It should match only the first and the fourth. The rest don't match the criterion of being all positive and ending in zero.

Here's what we do:

```
runs = Last@Reap[data //. {a___, pat : PatternSequence[{_, _, _?Positive} .., {_, _, 0}], b___} :> (Sow[{pat}]; {a, Unique[], b})]
(* {{{{0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0}}
   , {{-1, 11, 10}, {10, -4, 6}, {6, -6, 0}}}} *)
```

The logic is as follows. We match a run to the sequence with the pattern

```
{a___, pat : PatternSequence[{_, _, _?Positive} .., {_, _, 0}], b___}
```

which uses the `Repeated` (`..`) pattern to indicate that there are repeated elements all matching `{_, _, _?Positive}`. We name the pattern `pat` so that we can `Sow` the resulting match and `Reap` it later. We use replacement rules to take out the matched bit so that it won't get matched again, replacing it with a `Unique` place-holder, and we use `ReplaceRepeated` to do this until we've found all of the runs.

Just to see what happens to the actual list:

```
First@Reap[data //. {a___, pat : PatternSequence[{_, _, _?Positive} .., {_, _, 0}], b___} :> (Sow[{pat}]; {a, Unique[], b})]
(* {$3, {0, -6, -6}, {-6, 8, 2}, {2, 9, 11}, {11, 6, 17}, {17, -18, -1}, $4, {-1, 1, 0}, {9, -9, 0}} *)
```

The runs have been replaced by `Unique` variables `$3` and `$4`, and the rest of the list remains unaltered.

**Original Post**

I think you need to embed the `PatternSequence` inside the list, like so:

```
{a___, pat : PatternSequence[{_, _, _?Positive}, {_, _, 0}], b___}
```

I'm going to take a slightly different take on this. I'm not entirely sure `Cases` is the best choice here, but what I'm about to show might not work either for the general case. I took the liberty of changing the last element of your list to illustrate that for this specific pattern, it will choose the `Shortest` automatically, because pattern-matching is automatically greedy from the *end* of the list (I think that's how that works). Anyway:

```
data = {{0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0}, {0, -6, -6}, {-6, 8, 2}, {2, 9, 11}, {11, 6, 17}, {17, -10, 7}, {7, 10, 17}, {17, 2, 19}, {19, -10, 9}, {9, -9, 0}};
Last@Reap[
   data /. {a___, pat : PatternSequence[{_, _, _?Positive}, ___, {_, _, 0}], b___} :> (Sow[{pat}]; {a, pat, b})
  ]
(* {{{{0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0}}}} *)
```

Note that if we add `Longest@` in front of `PatternSequence`, it returns the whole list, illustrating the "greediness-from-the-end" pattern-matching behavior.

---

For fun, here's another generator for your list:

```
randomArray[range_List, length_Integer] := With[{first = RandomInteger[range]}
  , NestList[{#1, #2, #1 + #2} & @@ {Last@#, RandomInteger[range]} &, {0, first, first}, length - 1]
 ]
```

---

I'm definitely interested in the actual problem you want to solve, so please leave comments.

Comment: thanks again.  That's a good start.  It may help also to show how I solved the problem using `Split[]`.  I will apply it to the test data you have in this answer.  Here is the code: `Split[data, Sign[Last@#1] == Sign[Last@#2] || Sign[Last@#2] == 0 &]` which gives `{{{0, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0}}, {{0, -6, -6}}, {{-6, 8, 2}, {2, 9, 11}, {11,
    6, 17}, {17, -10, 7}, {7, 10, 17}, {17, 2, 19}, {19, -10, 
   9}, {9, -9, 0}}}`.  You'll notice this lists out each run as an element of the returned list.  I will share more about my problem a bit later as I'm short on time now.  Thanks again!

Comment: I may have stumbled upon the answer using `SequenceCases[]` and this very concise expression `SequenceCases[data, {{_, _, _?Positive} .., {_, _, _?PossibleZeroQ}}]`.  I'll review tomorrow and revert.

Comment: I keep forgetting about `SequenceCases` since I only have *Mathematica* 10.0, and it was introduced in 10.1, but that's a good idea. Now that I understand what you are trying to do, I'll update my answer. But I recommend including the `Split` version in your question, just for completeness, or you can post an answer to your question, because why not? EDIT: one last point: why do you use `_?PossibleZeroQ` instead of just `0`?

Comment: @rfrasier-mlp. I have posted an updated answer. Does it work? (I think it does.)

Comment: thank you again.  I am using `_?PossibleZeroQ` honestly just for code readability, consistency in using `PatternTest[]`, and robustness to so it can handle real-valued arrays so I don't forget to change it from `0` later :-)